# Is this actually open to SQL injection?

Tags: postgresql, sql-injection

We have a function that builds some XML and uses EXECUTE/USING to try to prevent SQL injection. It's along the lines of:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f1(t TEXT)
    RETURNS XML AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    ret_val XML;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT ''<'' || $1 || ''>'''
    --rest of xml building
    INTO ret_val
    USING t;
    RETURN ret_val;
END
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

I don't like this much due to the concatenation. It would be much better if we could just do `SELECT '''<$1>''` but that ends up with a literal $1 rather than replacing it with the value.

Due to the concatenation, it's making me wonder whether we even need SQL injection prevention here. It's not reading from a table, just building an XML string which is returned.

Is there any actual risk from not using `USING` in this case? Does concatenating $1 negate the effects of `USING`, or does `USING` even have any effect on a statement that doesn't use a table?

Comment: Do any variables from any end user end up inside there?

Comment: @castis Yes for example the `t` arg is used for the element name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to unpack here.

Firstly, the SQL you have there is actually a fixed string:

```
'SELECT ''<'' || $1 || ''>'''
```

So nothing can be directly injected here, because there's no dynamic SQL. As Laurenz Albe pointed out, the SQL in this particular example could be written as a non-dynamic statement:

```
SELECT '<' || t || '>'
```

There is still no SQL injection here, because you're not *evaluating* the contents of `t`, just manipulating it as a string, just as `SELECT a + 1` would manipulate `a` as a number.

The key point is that the actual SQL is hard-coded, and the concatenation is just the instruction in that SQL.

Note that this similar-looking query *would* be dangerous (the syntax highlighting gives a clue to the difference):

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT ''<' || t || '>''' -- DON'T DO THIS!
```

Here, the value of `t` is being used *as part of the SQL string* - the concatenation is happening first, *and then* the result is executed. So a value of `'1'; DROP TABLE users; --'` would result in the query `SELECT '<1'; DROP TABLE users; --` which is clearly undesirable.

Secondly, as [explained in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), the `$1` is a *parameter*, supplied by the `USING` clause *as data*, so it too is safe from SQL injection. This is similar to using a parameterised query in a programming language outside the database - you build up the query as a string, carefully whitelisting the tables and columns referenced, then provide the variable data separately, where it cannot be reinterpreted as SQL. Or to put it another way, it's like another function "one level deeper", with the parameters specified by the USING clause acting just like the parameters to an actual function.

Finally, though, a note of caution: you *are* vulnerable to *XML injection*: if nothing else has validated or escaped `t`, you could generate invalid or dangerous XML. For instance, consider what would happen if the value of `t` was `'foo><script>alert("Hello, world!");</script></foo'` and the result ended up parsed as HTML.

Comment: So in my particular case, I don't really gain anything by the `USING` statement over a simple `EXECUTE 'SELECT ''<' || t || '>'''`? I should have noted this earlier, but the function must remain plpgsql.

Comment: @eurotrash If the string of SQL you are executing is exactly the same every time the function is run, then coding that SQL directly inside the function will be exactly the same as coding it using an `EXECUTE` statement. Think of the SQL inside `EXECUTE` as like another function "one level deeper", with the parameters specified by the `USING` clause acting just like the parameters to an actual function. It's only useful if the actual SQL to run changes, e.g. using different columns or tables, changing an `ORDER BY` clause, etc.

Comment: Isn't the `EXECUTE` going to evaluate it? What if `t` contains some bad SQL, won't this be concatenated with `SELECT '<'` to form a new SQL statement that will be executed by `EXECUTE`?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen No, because the string passed to `EXECUTE` is the hard-coded string shown; the concatenation is part of the execution, not part of constructing the query. It's easy to confuse it with the visually similar `EXECUTE 'SELECT ''<' || t || '>'''`, which *is* dynamically constructing the SQL, but that's not what's happening here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no danger for SQL injection here, because you are using `USING`.

Note that you could have been using static SQL to achieve the same thing:

```
SELECT '<' || t || '>' INTO ret_val;
```

Comment: "Not" or "Note"? In your example you're not using `USING`, are you saying that would be fine?

Comment: "Note". Sorry. Both your dynamic query and the static one I quote do the same thing, and both are safe.